# List<User> Property Not Generated With Ria Service

Tags: silverlight, ria

I have a RIA service and I am finding that my regular properties are being generated for RIA service (ex: string, int, etc).

I have a custom type User which is described below.  My List property is not being generated as part of the Ria service.  Any ideas?

Example below shows the property that is not being generated in RIA Service followed by the User class

```
    public List<User> Users
    {
        get
        {
            if(this.users == null)
            {
                this.users = new List<User>();
            }
            return this.users;
        }
        set
        {
            this.users = new List<User>(value);
        }
    }





using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public int? Id { get; set; }

        public string Login { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string DisplayName { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }

        public string Title
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string Department
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string Password { get; set; }

        public string Source { get; set; }

        public bool? IsEnabled { get; set; }

        public bool IsInstanceAdmin { get; set; }

        public byte[] Image { get; set; }

        //public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

        private IList<UserGroupMembership> _userGroups;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the user groups.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The user groups.</value>
        [Include]
        [Association("UserGroups", "Id", "UserId")]
        public IList<UserGroupMembership> UserGroups
        {
            get
            {
                if (_userGroups == null)
                {
                    _userGroups = new List<UserGroupMembership>();
                }
                return _userGroups;
            }
            set
            {
                _userGroups = value;
            }
        }


        private IList<RoleAssignment> _roleIdentity;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the role identities.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The role identities.</value>
        [Include]
        [Association("RoleIdentities", "Id", "UserId")]
        public IList<RoleAssignment> RoleAssignments
        {
            get
            {
                if (_roleIdentity == null)
                {
                    _roleIdentity = new List<RoleAssignment>();
                }
                return _roleIdentity;
            }
            set
            {
                _roleIdentity = value;
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a User query which exposes it to the client? Because you cant expose any Domain Service type through a POCO object! It must be in a query within the Domain Service.